# MVC 5 - PDF form within iframe to save in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, iframe, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently working on a web application in MVC 5. I need the users to fill in pdf form which will be stored in an iframe which then has to be stored directly into the database instead of the user downloading the pdf and uploading it again.

My question is how would I go about doing this? 
I would need to alter the file name per response from user while storing the newly filled in pdf. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If possible, could someone provide a code example.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know you need a third party component in order to save PDF  displayed inside browser straight to database. For example, [Active PDF](https://www.activepdf.com/products/portal). *I'm sure Active PDF can do it, because I have done it before*.

Comment: Which product of Active PDF did you use? Also do you have a code example of it being used?

Comment: I used [Active PDF Portal](https://www.activepdf.com/products/portal). It is quite simple to use *(and also has some limitations)*. You can see the document [here](http://examples.activepdf.com/Portal/2014/Basic_Portal.cs). You can contact them if you want more details about the product.

Comment: Thank you for your help:) Quick question...Would it be easier to convert a view with textboxes and such to PDF and then store it in the database?

Comment: What Active PDF does is you need an editable PDF first. It saves the original PDF as template in database. When a user enters the data, it greps the data and save them into database without underlying PDF.